# Is there any way to allow users to access content before it's published?

Tags: posts, users

I have a blog and I make posts daily, and I would like for users to be able to access posts one day before they are published. How can I do that?

Comment: Which users and how?

Comment: Any registered user.

Comment: And were you thinking of a shortcode, widget, page template? These are scheduled posts?

Comment: Yes, they're scheduled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in a template file:

```
$tomr = getdate(time()+86400); //utc=gmt time in seconds, add 24 hours = 86400 seconds
$args = array(
  'post_status' => 'future',
  'date_query'  => array(
    array(
        'year'   => $tomr['year'],
        'month'  => $tomr['mon'],
        'day'    => $tomr['mday'],
        'column' => 'post_date_gmt' //since we are using the gmt timestamp
    ),
  ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()) {
  while($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    //display post data
  }
  //restore original post data if it's required after this loop
  wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
  //no posts found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few plugins that may be useful to you:

- [WP-DraftsForFriends](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-draftsforfriends/)
- [Public Post Preview](https://wordpress.org/plugins/public-post-preview/)

I prefer **WP-DraftsForFriends** as it has an admin page to control expiration and renew for longer periods of time. It's also nice to see all of your public links in one area rather than Public Post Preview which is only controlled on the post edit screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a post in admin and give post link to user, Like suppose you want to publish post tomorrow then just create post and put publish date for tomorrow.
So post will publicly displayed tomorrow. but you can share that post link to anyone.

Comment: As far as I understand, only admins can see the post before its published with the URL.